# Macro to match colums is getting error

Tags: excel, match, vba

I want to check if cells in a column on sheet1 are in a column in sheet2 if it is then do `nothing` if it is `not` then past its value in the last row + 1

I get `type mismatch` on this line
`If Application.Match(FindValues(i, 1), wsTarget.Range("A2:A" & sLR), 0) = False Then`
Edit: This works
Thanks

```
'\\ IF cell found in match range then do sothing if not dosomthing else
Sub FindReplace_Updated_Blanks()
Dim FindValues As Variant
Dim ReplaceValues As Variant
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim sLR As Long
Dim tLR As Long
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Updated_Blanks").Select

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blanks")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Updated_Blanks")

          sLR = wsSource.Range("B" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
          tLR = wsTarget.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   FindValues = wsSource.Range("B2:B" & sLR).Value

    For i = LBound(FindValues) To UBound(FindValues)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(FindValues(i, 1), wsTarget.Range("A2:A" & tLR), 0)) Then

        Else
            wsTarget.Range("A" & (tLR + 1)) = FindValues(i, 1)

          End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see generic messages like this when you use `Application.WorksheetFunctions`, or in this case `Application.Match()`. Most likely your `Application.Match` is returning a #N/A error, which VBA says is a "Type Mismatch" which is pretty generic.

You can see this error (Error 2042) if you assign the result of your `Application.MAtch()` formula to a variable and then print that variable value out. No worries though since #N/A is an expected result of the Match() Excel formula.

Comment: Thanks JNevil that help me get to the answer.  I updated the code to what works.